# Creating a setter to a relation in Parse subclass

Tags: c#, parse-platform

How the relation "Status" field setter should looks like ?

```
[ParseClassName("ClipV2")]
public class ClipV2 : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName("clipId")]
    public string ID
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("status")]
    public ParseRelation<ClipStatus> Status
    {
        get { return GetRelationProperty<ClipStatus>(); }
        set { ??? }
    }
}


[ParseClassName("ClipStatus")]
public class ClipStatus : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName("status")]
    public string Status
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value); }
    }
}
```

What I looking for is an easy way to update my related status (one -> many)
and I can't find out a fine example in Parse.com documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think I found a way:

```
var relation = clipObject.Status ; 

relation.Add(clipStatusObject);

await clipObject.SaveAsync();
```

I think the object you add to the relation has to be saved, if its a new object. Hope it helps!